# Can we reopen the question about how to evaluate if your job is a "good" job or not?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I really liked [pap's answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/9508/316) to the question [What does it actually mean by a good job?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/9496/316). His answer provides some great information that would be very valuable to our community members, so am making an attempt to "save" that question.

I made [some edits](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/revisions/9496/3) to it to refocus the question a bit last week, and would like to know if the edits are enough to get the question reopened.

It had 4 reopen votes yesterday, but I see today that one has expired so it's down to 3.

Is the edit I did to the question to re-focus the question on how to evaluate if a job is a "good" job or not enough to get the question reopened? And if not, is there another edit we could make to the question to get it reopened?

Answer (score 3):

Most questions on this site have a couple of "[it depends](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/148/17)" factors that a good answer will take into account, and give a couple of different options.

However, with more than one or two, we get quickly to a point where **no single answerer can hope to cover all ground** and give a "correct" answer to the question.

This, in turn, means that there are **many "right" answers** that our readers will deem "helpful".  We often attract many "good" answers to "bad" (bad subjective) questions.

The result, of course, is that we get way too many answers (some repeating others), upvote pile-ons, fastest-gun problem (too many answers to pick the right one over the first/early ones), exploding comment threads, and generally all sorts of things that **don't work right in Stack Exchange format**.

And here is a list of things that this question "depends" on.

- Where you live
- What your goals are
- What industry you are in
- Your skills
- Your credentials
- Why you are looking for a new job
- What you like
- What you dislike
- Your personality type

As Chad has said, narrow this down to one "it depends" variable, and you have a totally different question.

**Good answers don't make good questions.**  However, this might make a *great* blog post topic (blog posts are great for "this won't cover everything, but it will get you thinking" type questions).

Comment: Would an edit specifying that it is looking for generic questions to ask when evaluating a job that would be the same regardless of location, personality, industry, etc make it an OK StackExchange question? I believe that was the OP's intent, as they did not include any specifics in their question, and that is what Pap's answer covers.

Comment: @Rachel Doesn't that violate the principle of "no questions looking for lists of answers"?  This is such a **giant** topic, I don't see how one answer could give a reasonable starting point without fewer variables.

Answer (score 2):

### NO

This question should not be reopened.

I wanted to leave this question closed but on the site because it has a good answer... but it is a horrible question.  So as a result of the push to open it I have voted to delete and hope others will join with me.

Comment: Why do you think it cannot be saved and should not be reopened?

Comment: It is a discussion question and no changes to the question will ever change that without completely changing the question.

Answer (score 2):

This question has no answer.

Any answer is mostly subjective, largely culturally specific, and completely a discussion regardless.

The only way I would consider that a good Stack Exchange question is if instead of "how can I evaluate if a job meets a set of criteria which differs for every person based on their personal value system, cultural norms, and lifestyle?" it was something more specific than... that.